# Использование ActiveX контрола не в форме, а в классе

Tags: c#, winforms, activex

Есть ActiveX контрол, предоставляющий определенный функционал.

Есть ли возможность в .NET использовать его не в форме, а в классе\статическом классе?

Т.е. не требуется его визуальное отображение, нужна лишь его механика.

Пробовал подобным образом вызывать его из класса: (myControl as Control).CreateControl();

сами понимаете - ничего путного. NullReferenceException.

**update**

Немого покопался, использовав оболочку Ax пытаюсь создать объект (т.е. уже без as): `myControl.CreateControl();`

Выдает исключение: "Данный элемент управления ActiveX является неоконным и не поддерживается в этой версии .NET Framework." (System.InvalidOperationException)

**update 2**

Нашел похожую проблему с контролом ActiveX: [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198725/running-com-component-controls-on-multiple-threads)

Там тема заглохла. Есть ли еще варианты?

**update 3**

Тестовый проект на базе RDP Client контрола: [ссылка](https://www.sendspace.com/file/l6odo2)

Comment: А почему не работать с ним как с любым COM-объектом? Project -> AddReference -> COM ... ?

Comment: Ну или через TLBIMP

Comment: VladD, спасибо, попробую. По результатам отпишу.

Comment: Не забудьте, что COM-объект (если он AcitveX) скорее всего можно использовать лишь в STA-thread'е.

Comment: Вот вам [документация](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6tx9dw3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) на всякий случай.

Comment: Пробовал и на своем контроле, и на RDP Client (ссылка на тему выше) контроле от мелкомягких. Что только не делал - все бестолку.

Comment: А что именно не выходит? На какой стадии проблема?

Comment: Смотрите. На примере RDP клиента. Он есть в панели элементов: http://i6.5cm.ru/i/5ULL.png но его нету в COM библиотеках: http://i6.5cm.ru/i/BfgU.png Т.е. не могу добавить контрол как COM объект. Если нужно - могу сделать тестовый проект на базе рдп клиента в классе, чтобы было понятно о чем я. Пробовал через tlbimp.exe опять же на примере рдп клиента - при сборке выдал кучу ошибок. По факту все тоже самое, молча не работает соединение, я даже снифером пакеты смотрел - пакеты не идут. Пробовал как в STA потоке так и нет. В общем массу вариантов.

Comment: Тогда возможно у вас COM-объект не зарегистрирован в системе? (regsvr32 из-под админа) Или если у вас он reg-free, нету нужного манифеста. Или можно попробовать создать через TLBIMP interop-библиотеку и подключать её. Должно по идее работать.

Comment: А откуда сам ActiveX-контрол берётся?

Comment: И что говорит TLBIMP?

Comment: Regsvr32 из-под админа - пробовал. Ошибка при импорте из COM reference. Через TLBIMP пробовал, тоже самое. Скрин ошибок на примере RDP клиента: http://i6.5cm.ru/i/g9qS.png Через 15 минут сделаю тестовый проект на базе RDP клиента, чтобы понятнее было о чем я.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скрытая форма - единственный вариант. Ошибка, которую вы получаете, в английском варианте звучит как Unable to get window handle, Windowless ActiveX controls are not supported - "ActiveX вне форм не поддерживаются".

ActiveX задумывался прежде всего как фреймворк для визуальных элементов. Поэтому вся ифраструктура для них просто не работает, пока контрол не будет помещен на форму.

Можно скрестить пальцы и вызвать `CreateControl` у наследника `AxHost`:

```
public static void SomeMethod()
{
    var axSkype1 = new AxSKYPE4COMLib.AxSkype();
    axSkype1.CreateControl();

    Debug.WriteLine(axSkype1.RecentChats.Count);
}
```

нужны будут референсы на `AxSomeLib`, `SomeLib` и `System.Windows.Forms` если повезет - будет работать. Но все равно будут некоторые ограничения на поток, в котором это можно сделать.

Comment: Есть ли какая либо возможность обмануть контрол подсунув фейковую\неинициализированную форму? Любой вариант, мысли, догадки и пр.

Comment: попробуйте влоб, через CreateControl.

Comment: Через CreateControl пробовал. System.InvalidOperationException именно от CreateControl. Без CreateControl молча ничего не работает просто напросто.

Comment: Значит вам не повезло, и ваш контрол пытается быть действительно визуальным, что без формы у него не получается.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать все же хостить его на форме, но форму сделать скрытой. Форму можно сделать удобным враппером к имеющемуся функционалу ActiveX-контрола, если в этом будет необходимость.

Comment: Memoizer, со скрытой формой все понятно, причем это быстро и удобно. Но нужно именно в классе. Немного обновил вопрос.